# Add a quantity if item already exists in data grid view selected list

Tags: vb.net

I am facing problem to add quantity on datagridview2 quantity cell  if item is already exists in datagridview2

I have two datagridviews.

1. Datagridview1 contains items list their price and quantity
2. Datagridview2 contains items that is selected by customers their quantity and price.

My code for check for item exist in datagridview is:

```
If DataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0 Then

    Dim Found As Boolean = False

    For Each rw1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows

        For Each rw2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows

            If rw1.Cells("Item").Value = rw2.Cells("Column2").Value Then

                rw2.Cells("Column5").Value = rw2.Cells("Column5").Value + 1
                Found = True

            ElseIf Not Found Then

                For Each dr In Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows

                    Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(rw1.Cells(1).Value, 1, rw1.Cells(3).Value)

                Next
                Exit For
            End If                  
        Next  
    Next
End If
```

When i select the the row first time it check the the row and add quantity, But when I select second time it doesn't check and just add row to datagridview.

My application form is like:

[Image shows that the when I select second time it doesn't check and just add row to datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx1eF.png) 
[debug result. That shows that rw2.cell contains the value of Row 1. and it is not changing, thats why the condition remain false.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP1In.png)

I fixed my code :

```
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim Found As Boolean = False
    For Each rw1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        For Each rw2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows

            If rw1.Cells("Item").Value = rw2.Cells("Column2").Value Then

                rw2.Cells("Column5").Value = rw2.Cells("Column5").Value + 1
                Found = True
                'Subtracting Quantity from Datagridview1
                For Each sqt As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
                    sqt.Cells(2).Value = sqt.Cells(2).Value - 1
                Next
                'calculating Amount
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
                    row.Cells("Column6").Value = row.Cells("Column5").Value * row.Cells("Column3").Value
                Next
                ' Calculating Total Amount
                '  Dim sum As Integer = 0
                For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
                    sum = sum + DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Column6").Value
                Next
                TextBox1.Text = sum.ToString()
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For Each dr In Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(dr.Cells(1).Value, 1, dr.Cells(3).Value) 
    Next
```

Comment: I'll wager that you haven't actually debugged your code yet.  Don't just read it.  Place a breakpoint at the top of the code and then step through it as it executes.  You can then see exactly where it behaves differently to your expectation and also what data is in use at that time that causes it to do so.  Even if you still can't fix the issue yourself, at least you can provide us with more useful information.

Comment: That said, my guess would be that you're not resetting `Found` before executing that code, so it will use the value it ended with last time.  Of course, you'd have seen that if you had debugged.

Comment: The problem is rw2 cell value is not updating. when i select second row from datagridview1 to add into  datagridview2, The rw1.cell value changed but rw2.cell remain unchanged, rw2 contains value of first row of datagridview2. I want that if select to add any row from datagridview1  it checks that datagridview1 with the rowof current row index.

Comment: Have you debugged the code?

Comment: Result from when i add 1st time: rw1.Cells("Item").Value "Admit 50/1000" ,,, and rw2.Cells("Column2").Value "Admit 50/1000" AND WHEN I SELECT 2ND ROW TO ADD INTO DGV2 THE RESULT IS: rw1.Cells("Item").Value "Advant 16mg" AND rw2.Cells("Column2").Value "Admit 50/1000"

Comment: Yes i  debugged it and upload the result in question please the picture uploaded.. jmcilhinney